# handlebar.js accessing objects within a lambda function

Tags: handlebars.js, mustache

I'm trying to access an nested object within an lamda function. The object looks similar to this:

```
{
  foo: function(){
    return {
      'bar': "success"
    }
  }
}
```

when I try to access it with `{{foo.bar}}` it returns an empty string. If I wrap it with `{{#foo}}{{bar}}{{/foo}}` it works. Is this intentional ? Is there any way i can make the first statement work ? The templates are already in use for mustache.php and i'm trying to make then work in the frontend as well.

Here is a working demonstration of the problem:

```js
var obj = {
  foo: function(){
    return {
      'bar': "success"
    }
  }
};

var source   = document.getElementById("template").innerHTML;
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = template(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.11/handlebars.js"></script>

<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
nested: {{#foo}}{{bar}}{{/foo}} <br/>
dot notation: {{foo.bar}}
</script>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: I wonder why using a function instead of using an attribute for your variable : {foo:{"bar":"success"}} would do the job you intend, so why using a function ?

Comment: this is just a minimal example, that supposed to demonstrate the problem. In the real world i'm dealing with a more complex data structure that encapsulate/decorate a lot of values through functions, for logging/security/utility reasons. So almost every object-property has a "getter"-function.

Comment: Just noticed that this statement will also provide you with the same output in this case `{{#each foo}}{{this}}{{/each}}`. Would have got something to do with the `#` operator which traverses/iterates through the object.